# Apache2 with mod_proxy_ajp doesn't rewrite url

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, mod-proxy, mod-jk

I have apache2 exposing a jboss through mod_proxy_ajp on / and serving some static content with

```
ProxyPass /static !
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

in proxy_ajp.conf. 
I need to redirect all the traffic on www.example.com to example.com and it works for all the static resources in /static but if I retrieve www.example.com/hello the url is not rewritten.

My Virtual Host config is the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        RedirectMatch 301 (.*) http://example.com$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

What is wrong? I think that proxy_ajp is catching the request before is pass through apache and the url is redirected.

Comment: Did the answer given by @H.-Dirk Schmitt work? I am looking for the same answer. If so give it a check so I and others can know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have forgotten the `ProxyPassReverse` statement. It has the same parameters as the `ProxyPass` statement.

Try:

```
 ProxyPass        /static !
 ProxyPass        / ajp://localhost:8009/
 ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```